# How can I get this table in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
e=[]
for i in sales_data.columns:
    print(i, sales_data[i].nunique())
    e.append(sales_data[i].nunique())
e
```

The code gives the following output-

```
SaleID 100
RetailerCountry 11
RetailerType 7
Product 71
Sales Revenue ($) 66
DateOfSale 94
TimeOfSale 100
TimeZone 6
```

How Can I get this in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: did you read the docstring for dataframe?

Comment: How do you want the dataframe to look?  Do you want a two column 8 row DF or do you want an 8 column 1 row DF?  Please provide a sample of your expected output.

Comment: In any case, as is typically, you don't need a loop at all. `sales_data.nunique(axis=0)` will get you the desired result

Comment: @itprorh66 
I wanted 2 columns and 8 rows. Just in a DataFrame format.

Comment: @Paul H, 
Your suggestion works